# Manage azure cloud via PowerShell - access problem

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

In my Azure environment I have MFA configured (MFA enabled using Security Default in Azure AD). I want to connect to Azure using Azure Powershell. I am using cmdlet

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription "SubscriptionID"
```

I have a Global Administrator role in Azure AD, and Owner role on the subscription level. Before MFA I was able to `Connect-AzAccount` without any problems. Now when I am trying to `Connect-AzAccount` I am getting information:

```
WARNING: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXCCAADDFF to authenticate.
```

I do recommended steps, using provided link providing code. After around 20 seconds I am getting an error message in the PowerShell console

```
Connect-AzAccount: The provided account xx.yy@company.com does not have access to subscription ID "SubscriptionID". Please try logging in with different credentials or a different subscription ID.
```

Comment: for the cmdlet, are you passing any creds to it?

Comment: No, I am using only `Connect-AzAccount`, then receiving message `WARNING: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXCCAADDFF to authenticate.`, and in the browse I am following the instructions proveided in that message (link and code)

Comment: Have you tried running `Connect-AzAccount` without passing the `-Subscription` parameter? You can then set the right subscription in your PS context with the `Set-AzContext` cmdlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `code XXCCAADDFF` mentioned in warning message refers to device code, it may be caused by you enable device login.

You mentioned getting error message `The provided account xx.yy@company.com does not have access to subscription ID....`, you can use

```
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId <tenantId> -Subscription <subscriptionId>
```

instead of

```
Connect-AzAccount -Subscription <subscriptionId>
```

For this problem, here is a [post](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9677) related to it. I also test it in my side, just add `-TenantId`, it will solve the error message.